# Flink with Ceph as the persistent storage

Tags: apache-flink, ceph

Flink documents suggests that Ceph can be used as a persistent storage for states. https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/stream/checkpointing.html

Considering that Ceph is a transactional database, wouldn't it have adverse effect on Flink's performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Ceph](https://ceph.com) describes itself as a *"unified, distributed storage system"* and provides a network file system API. As such, it such should be seamlessly working with Flink's state backends that persist checkpoints to a remote file system.

I'm not aware of people using Ceph (HDFS and S3 are more commonly used) and have no information about the performance. However, note that Flink is able to write checkpoints asynchronously, such that the performance of the storage system does not affect the processing speed of a Flink application. It might however, constrain the interval in which checkpoints are taken.

**Update:**
(Feb. 2018) I noticed that multiple users reported on Flink's user mailing list that they are using Ceph with Flink.

**Update 2:**
Flink is working fine with S3 protocol and both ([Presto & Hadoop](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/filesystems/s3.html#hadooppresto-s3-file-systems-plugins)) Flink's S3 FileSystem plugins are working fine with it.

Comment: For example, see http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/flink-user/201802.mbox/%3CCAOmfQNobEGf74wazoCsWWTUUrEDMDc-V=jzHXWbjF2ZLxAEw8A@mail.gmail.com%3E

Comment: Is there any guieds for configure CEPH as Apache Flink checkpointing?
As i can see from the link - i should mount ceph dir to every node of Apache Flink and work as file://

Is it right way?

Comment: It seems to be working via S3 protocol too. You should configure: s3://testflink/bootstrapjob, where testflink is a bucket in Ceph. To authenticate we should pass: s3.access-key, s3.secrect-key. s3.endpoint should be configured to your Ceph endpoint, otherwise by default Flink would point to aws.