# Configuration to use CEPH as persistent storage?

Tags: apache-flink, ceph

I need to check performance of flink with Ceph storage.
But I am not getting flink configuration for Ceph as storage.

Could anyone post a configuration of flink with Ceph as a storage backend?

Comment: Apache-flink configuration for CEPH as persistent storage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flink with Ceph as the persistent storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47652024/flink-with-ceph-as-the-persistent-storage)

Comment: @David Anderson: Yes this question is duplicate of that you have mentioned. But in this haven't get relevant answer. So created new thread.

Comment: Last week I added a comment in the other thread pointing to the info you're looking for.